# Server-side login with Facebook app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-login

I would like to have my iOS and Android app offer Facebook login via the native Facebook app rather than a web view. Literally all of the documentation I have found seems to talk about client-side-only authentication, that is, the client talks to Facebook and then receives an `access_token` out of the deal.

I need the ability to authenticate the user with my server. This means I need my server in the middle, receiving the redirect from Facebook and then authenticating the user.

If I wanted to use a web view, that's pretty straightforward. However, I can find zero documentation detailing how to do this with the Facebook native apps. Is there any? Or am I missing something dumb/simple?

Comment: Can't your client pass the access token to your server?

Comment: Have a look at this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Comment: @KrishnaPradyumnaMokshagundam So you're saying that the client needs to pass the access token to the server, which then independently goes to Facebook to verify credentials? The ordinary OAuth2 flow is that the authentication server passes the access token to the server, which then passes it to the client.

Comment: @chRyNaN I don't see anything in that link relevant to native auth, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time looking into how the Facebook SDK does this on iOS while building Stormpath's iOS SDK (we re-implemented Facebook's login flow to avoid needing another dependency), and I believe I know why Facebook and Google are moving to using the web view instead of their native apps.

In iOS 9, `SFSafariWebView` was released, which is really awesome because unlike `WKWebView` or `UIWebView`, `SFSafariWebView` has access to all of your user's cookies. That means when opening a link to Facebook's login screen in the web view, your user is already logged in.

Because they never get directed out of your app, it's actually faster and a better user experience to use the web view than using the Facebook app to authenticate your user.

However, since the Facebook iOS SDK is open-source, you can check out `performNativeLogInWithParameters:handler:` in [FBSDKLoginManager.m](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/dab4a58b5a3b6230d46e9e1a036a45547c028539/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.m#L451) to see how they implement it, and modify the internals so it forces the native app login.